# Matrix puzzle doesn't make sense to me

Tags: progressive-matrix

Found this one in a WA group. Nobody answered it and I can't say I have a clear solution to it.

Comment: why did you delete the image...? - it is effectively deleting the whole question...--- ok looking at the edit comment....   '  The image was not allowed outside the WA group.'   I think this question should be deleted or at least closed...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because   The image required for the question had to be removed as it was not allowed outside a particular group (see comments)

Answer (score 3):

> Filled square. There is one copy of every blank shape and two of every filled shape.

Comment: Hell, its so obvious now!

Comment: I agree - on the basis of what things are, you beat me by 16 minutes

Comment: But the filling in the other shapes are in different directions. All details should be accounted for.

Comment: @Erin; well you've deleted the picture, so I can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

Mmh after checking it twice I am hesitating between white circle and white triangle

- Vertical (chess)mirroring of the image implies white circle
- ... but "all elements are duplicated except the bulls eye" implies white triangle
- Indeed if you see it row-wise as A + B = C, where A element gives you C shape whereas B element NANDs A color, it can be both black or white circle

If this is in some kind of IQ test, I'd bet for solution one if it is at the beginning of the test, and probably solution two if it's further

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be an empty square, as you see there is 3 circles and 3 triangles but 2 squares. There are also 4 filled shapes but 3 empty ones (I mean just stroke).

in column 2 there are two circles and a triangle, in column 3 there are one circle, one triangle and one square, in the first column there is already one square and on triangle so if we assume missed shape is a square, then square and circle shape has 0,1,2 showing up in different columns.

as you see in the first line there are two filled shapes with one stroke one, second line consist of two stroked shapes and a filled one, so as a sequence it's expected from third line to have 2 filled and one stroked one.